# What is the correct doctype for glassfish-application-client.xml?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I get an error deploying an application to GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23). GlassFish complains that I've made a typo in my DOCTYPE tag, but I copied the DOCTYPE verbatim from [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaqo.html)! I used the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application-client PUBLIC ""-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Application Client 6.0//EN"" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application-client_6_0-1.dtd">
```

What is the correct one?

Comment: An issue has been created in GlassFish to track this: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19297

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct doctype has a "Java EE" before the "Application Client" (on the second line) and does not have the weird quadruple quotes. I have informed Oracle about this error in their documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application-client PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application Client 6.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application-client_6_0-1.dtd">
```

Comment: Correction: I _tried_ to contact Oracle about this, but the documentation feedback e-mail address just bounces mail back!

Comment: This is now [tracked](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19297) on the GlassFish bugs database. (Via Tim Quinn, who alluded to this in an answer that is no longer here.)